# error in namenode starting

Tags: hadoop, namenode

When i try to start the hadoop on master node i am getting the following output.and the namenode is not starting.

```
[hduser@dellnode1 ~]$ start-dfs.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dellnode1.library.out
dellnode1.library: datanode running as process 5123. Stop it first.
dellnode3.library: datanode running as process 4072. Stop it first.
dellnode2.library: datanode running as process 4670. Stop it first.
dellnode1.library: secondarynamenode running as process 5234. Stop it first.
[hduser@dellnode1 ~]$ jps
5696 Jps
5123 DataNode
5234 SecondaryNameNode
```

Comment: Did you check the Namenode log (default in `$HADOOP_HOME/logs`, I think)? Most of the time the info in there is pretty clear.

Comment: can you share your log files?

Comment: rather than using jps (which only shows processes for the current user), can you run a `ps axww | grep hadoop` on both your cluster nodes (dellnode1 and dellnode2) and paste that output back into your original question

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Stop it first".

- First call stop-all.sh
- Type jps
- Call start-all.sh (or start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh)
- Type jps (if namenode don't appear type "hadoop namenode" and check error)

Comment: What should a typical output look-like? I am getting only `15845 Jps`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257279/validate-start-dfs-sh

Comment: This method is Deprecated. so usage of 
stop-dfs.sh, 
stop-yarn.sh,
start-dfs.sh, 
start-yarn.sh 

is preferred

Answer (score 8):

According to running "stop-all.sh" on newer versions of hardoop, this is deprecated. You should instead use:

`stop-dfs.sh`

and

`stop-yarn.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Today, while executing pig scripts I got the same error mentioned in the question:

```
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-training-namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: /home/training/.bashrc: line 10: /jdk1.7.0_10/bin: No such file or directory
localhost: Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
localhost: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-training-datanode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: /home/training/.bashrc: line 10: /jdk1.7.0_10/bin: No such file or directory
localhost: Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
localhost: 
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-training-secondarynamenode-localhost.localdomain.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-training-jobtracker-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: /home/training/.bashrc: line 10: /jdk1.7.0_10/bin: No such file or directory
localhost: Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
localhost: 
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-training-tasktracker-localhost.localdomain.out
```

So, the answer is:

```
[training@localhost bin]$ stop-all.sh
```

and then type:

```
[training@localhost bin]$ start-all.sh
```

The issue will be resolved. Now you can run the pig script with mapreduce!

Answer (score 0):

In Mac (If you install using homebrew) Where 3.0.0 is Hadoop version. In Linux change the installation path accordingly(only this part will change . `/usr/local/Cellar/`).

```
> /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/stopyarn.sh
> /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/stopdfs.sh
> /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/stop-all.sh"
```

Better for pro users write this `alias` at the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`(If you are zsh user). And just type `hstop`from your command line everytime you want to stop Hadoop and all the related processes.

```
alias hstop="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/stop-yarn.sh;/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/stop-dfs.sh;/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/stop-all.sh"
```